# Как увидеть пароль авторизации у ростелека в браузере

Tags: html, веб-программирование, авторизация, провайдер

`Input type="text" name="passwd" maxlength="30" value="**********" />`

Такая тема тут не прокатила.

версия по

***F1744R_V1.56_RTC_20E_832***

Comment: Если хотите чтобы вам помогли то сформулируйте нормально вопрос!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help почитайте здесь как задавать  вопросы!

Comment: роутер настроен и работает в режиме ppoe. Его надо сбросить, а другой возможности сейчас искать карточку для авторизации в нет

Comment: `document.querySelector('[name=passwd]').value` в консоли браузера

Comment: после ввода в консоли 
document.querySelector('[name=passwd]').value
"**********"